# Can I turn one set of twinkle lights into several by cutting the wire & adding new plugs?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, cord-and-plug

I am working on a project for wedding reception lighting and would like to make several chandeliers using Christmas tree twinkle lights but the strands I have are way too long for one single chandelier. Ideally, I'd like to cut each twinkle light strand into 3 equal parts and then add a new two-prong plug to the end of each. I may also have to splice additional wire to make the cord part long enough to reach an outlet. Seems simple enough to me - but maybe I'm crazy?  Before I attempt, I want to make sure #1) this is safe if done correctly, and 2) do you have any experience to lend so that I have a successful project? Thank you very much!

Comment: It's going to depend on the type and manufacturer, but in my experience it's not as easy as you would think. It's easier to just buy shorter strings.

Comment: The vast majority of Christmas light strings, particularly with small bulbs, have the individual light in series. Thus a 120V string will have 10 x 12V bulbs or 15 x 9V bulbs, etc. If you cut such a string in half, you'll end up doubling the voltage on each bulb, making them very bright for the brief time before they burn out. As @Tester101 suggested, get shorter strings.

Comment: @DoxyLover: I don't think I've seen more than 50 lights in a series string, and most sets nowadays have more lights than that, with two or more strings in series.  Within a series string, the cable will have thee or four wires (depending upon whether the strings are in overlapping pairs).  Between strings, it will have two.  Inserting connectors at the places where the cable has only two wires should work; temporarily pulling a light will let you quickly find the ends of its associated string.